# Footnote - character instead of number

Tags: footnotes

I need footnote for image, however it gives me character to footnote instead of number. Could someone help me, how to change it to number?

```
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Pictures/a.png}
    \caption[asdf]{asdf \footnote[2]{\url{https://example.com}}}\label{fig:a} 
\end{minipage}
 \end{figure}
```

[image]

There is b instead of 2.

Comment: Note that the numbers in minipage footnotes may duplicate the numbers in normal footnotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something how this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}\centering
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption[asdf]{asdf \footnote[2]{\url{https://example.com}}}\label{fig:a}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it possible to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` to obtain the desired result.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks  = true,
    linkcolor   = blue,
    urlcolor    = red
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption[asdf]{Descritpion \footnotemark}\label{fig:a}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \footnotetext{\url{https://example.com}}
\end{document}
```